# plot with matplotlib inside loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using the plt library to create a diagram.
In this case I have a function to do some task and at the end draw a graph.

I created a loop with the function parameter and I want to display the graphs as a [3x3] matrix but I only get it to display them one by one consecutively.

here my code of my function

```
def dendrograma_test(datos, enlace, corte):
    Z = linkage(datos, enlace)
    dendrogram(Z, truncate_mode='lastp', p=12, leaf_rotation=45., color_threshold=corte, leaf_font_size=11., show_contracted=True)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.title('Dendrograma Jerarqueico con criterio' + enlace)
    plt.xlabel("Tamano del cluster")
    plt.ylabel('Distancia') # mide la distancia entre cluster
    if (corte == "default"):
        plt.axhline(y= 0.7*max(Z[:,2]))
    else:
        plt.axhline(y= corte)
    plt.show()
```

where I call this function

```
enlaces =["ward","average","centroid","single"]
cortes= ["default", 50, 25 ]

for enlace in enlaces:
    i = 1
    for corte in cortes:
        ax = plt.subplot(2,3,i)
        dendrograma_test(X, enlace, corte)
        i = i+1
```

Any suggestion to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want a figure with 9 total subplots? There are 12 combinations of enlaces and cortes ...

Comment: The `matplotlib` pages show you [how to stack subplots in two directions](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html). You must create a figure with subplots, catch the returned `axes` variable containing all axes, loop through these axes, tell your function to plot to one axis after the other, and use `plt.show()` outside your function.

Comment: check https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html for making subplots.